# Data encrypted in iOS and decrypted in Java server using AES ECB

Tags: java, ios, encryption, cryptography, porting

Java server using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding decrypted message. Android device could sent message and successfully decrypted by the java server. But when it turns to iOS, it doesn't work.

Android device encrypted data in the following code

```
public static String generateSalt() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    String salt = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    return salt;
}
public static String hashKey(String key, String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String combinedKey = key + salt;
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(combinedKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] hash = digest.digest();
    String hashedKey = String.format("%032X", new BigInteger(+1, hash));
    return hashedKey;
}
private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKey(String myKey) {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = null;
    byte[] key;
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        System.out.println(Base64.encode(key));
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        String a = Base64.encode(key);
        System.out.println("key:"+a);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return secretKey;
}
public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt, String secret) {
    String encodedEncryptedData = null;

    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = getSecretKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        //System.out.println(encryptedData);
        encodedEncryptedData = Base64.encode(encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return encodedEncryptedData;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String salt = generateSalt();
    String hash = hashKey("FEAD286FF2678F57C7865B6D6935C0C3",salt);
    //System.out.println(hash);
    String message = "60;50;28042017080701";
    String encryptedData = encrypt(message,hash);
    System.out.println(encryptedData);
}
```

The following code is the iOS AES encryption code:

```
+(NSString*) sha256:(NSString *)clear {
const char *s=[clear cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *keyData=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};
CC_SHA256(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);
NSData *out=[NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSString *hash=[out description];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
return hash.localizedUppercaseString;}


+(NSString*) getSecretKey:(NSString *)key {
const char *cstr = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:key.length];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (int)data.length, digest);
NSData * base64 = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:digest length:16];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[base64 base64EncodedDataWithOptions:kNilOptions] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return result;}
+ (NSString *)encryptAES:(NSString *)content key:(NSString *)key{
NSData *contentData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger dataLength = contentData.length;
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
memset(keyPtr, 0, sizeof(keyPtr));
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
size_t encryptSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *encryptedBytes = malloc(encryptSize);
size_t actualOutSize = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding|kCCOptionECBMode,  
                                      keyPtr,
                                      kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      nil,
                                      contentData.bytes,
                                      dataLength,
                                      encryptedBytes,
                                      encryptSize,
                                      &actualOutSize);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {

    return [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:encryptedBytes length:actualOutSize] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
}
free(encryptedBytes);
return nil;
return nil;
```

}

Comment: Compare the implementations carefully. There are obvious differences. Used string encoding (UTF8 vs ASCII) is one. Also google how to convert `NSString` to `NSData` and vice versa. You do not need `cstr` and you must not use `[out description]` (plus the replace stuff).

Comment: The key I created by the ios code is same with the one created by the java code. But the encrypted result is different. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Data: 60;50;28042017080701 Salt: seva2jnbepb0jcgvgkb4o07i1e hashKey:B6C5214DD1B2E9B2BB9EB538257897E82E202902D2108366D6FA411EE8C7D45D encrypted result: pR3Fnwi8Bfgmazg/eKXjr1BsghTIljbg3nQCqg9AAkE=
the above is the all the thing created by the java code. iOS created the same hashkey, but the result is DpsfEkIRRvk8gLN+4wf02Sd0posFToH3akw1rlvzlpk=

Comment: You are using UTF8 in Java, ACII in Obj-C. Instead of C string, use `data = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and `hash = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:out encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. Maybe post the expected and the actual result (example to test).

Comment: I tried, the problem is not in the SHA256 function. The hashKey generated by the ios and java is the same at this time.But after calling the encrypted functions. The result is totally different. The expected result is  pR3Fnwi8Bfgmazg/eKXjr1BsghTIljbg3nQCqg9AAkE=.

Comment: In `+ (NSString *)encryptAES:(NSString *)content key:(NSString *)key{`: content == @"60;50;28042017080701", key == @"B6C5214DD1B2E9B2BB9EB538257897E82E202902D2108366D6FA‌​411EE8C7D45D"?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: Sorry for delay. I get different results. How I understand, the only "problematic" method is `encrypt()`. Maybe update your question: remove everithing but `encrypt()`, shoe sample in and output to be able to reproduce and hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: I have solved the problem because I have encoded the key to Base64 String, hence the result is different. Instead of that, I use the key as NSData to encrypt, the result is true.

Comment: You said the key is correct :-(

Comment: Yep, it is correct. But using Base64 String as key does not work well, using the raw NSdata encrypted the data, then encode the data into Base64 String.